# Wrong result while trying to divide

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

To learn C++, I follow an online class and I am trying to create a console mode game.
The game take a random word, split the word and ask the user to guess the word.

When the user don't wanna play anymore and quit the game, my program show some statistics (total of game played, game wins ...).
While I am trying to get the win percentage, I get wrong result.

Explanation (*What I want*) :
My user win 1 game and lose 1 game -> 1/2 * 100 = 50% (win percentage)

What is wrong (*What I get*) :
My function return 0 for 1/2 * 100.

```
void gameStatistics(int gameNumber, int gameWin, int defeats, int tries)
{
    std::cout << "You quit." << std::endl;
    float const winpercentage=float(gameWin / gameNumber) * 100; // C4244, resolved by casting the int into float.
    std::cout << "Win average: " << winpercentage << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Statistics: Number of games played: " << gameNumber << " Number of win: " << gameWin << " Number of defeat: " << defeats << " Number of tries: " << tries << std::endl;
}
```

I have been struggling for a while and I need someone to explain what I am doing wrong.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1/2 = 0` in integer logic.

`1/2.0f = 0.5f` in float logic.

This line `float(gameWin / gameNumber)` means that divide in `integer` space then convert the result to `float` space.

You should do this:

```
float(gameWin) / gameNumber
```

or even better:

```
static_cast<float>(gameWin)/ gameNumber
```

Answer (score 3):

When you do `float(gameWin / gameNumber)` the division is still an *integer* division. You need to cast *one* of the operands as a float, like e.g. `float(gameWin) / gameNumber`.

Also note that unless you're on a small embedded platform, or writing code to run on a GPU, then there's really no reason to use `float` these days. Using `double` is just as "fast" as using `float`, and `double` is also the default floating point type (for example when using floating point literals).